# Why is this underscore here in this elixir function?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Going thru the [Programming Phoenix](https://media.pragprog.com/titles/phoenix/code/authentication/listings/rumbl/web/models/user.change1.ex) book, I see a function like:

```
defp put_pass_hash(changeset) do
    case changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: pass}} ->
        put_change(changeset, :password_hash, Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(pass))
      _ ->
        changeset
    end
 end
```

What is the "_" symbol doing there?

Comment: What you are asking is pretty basic stuff in Elixir, it's recommended that you start learn Elixir first, then learn the Phoenix framework, which is build on top of Elixir. Once you have basic understanding of Elixir, learning Phoenix will become much more easier.

Comment: @sbs it's better to give an answer with a note in bold what you said in your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Generally in Elixir when you use `_` in pattern matching you doesn't care about this value. For instance:

```
 {_ , data} = {:ok, body}
 data = body # true
```

I didn't want to put anywhere this `:ok` atom, so in pattern matching I left it.

Pattern matching is used in `case`. [Cas](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html)e is just `switch` in different programming languages. You can create many cases for expected values in one variable.
When using `_` in case, you usually put it as a last pattern matching in case, because it *matches all uncovered cases before*.

For instance:

```
def do_i_know_you(name) do
   case name do
     "Molly" -> "Hi Molly"
     "Tom" -> "Hi Tom"
     _ -> "I don't know who you are"
   end
end
```

In your particular `case` it checks whether your changeset is valid and the change is related with added password. If so, just put in this changeset `password_hash`, based on your password. If not, just return unchanged changeset.

You could easily apply here `if do end`, but `case` and `cond` are usually preffered in Elixir and Phoenix.

Answer (score 2):

In patter matching `_` simply means it would match anything. 
Its quite common in `case` statements to have `_` as the last pattern to match.

Lets try to answer your question *why is there an underscore here*. In common practice when we pattern match with case, we are looking for some specific patterns that we know can occur. Example -

```
  case match_me do
   :bold -> "Have some bold text"
   :italic -> "Have some italic text"
   _ -> "Have some text"
  end
```

When we match, we know what to do for the first two patterns,its a specific case. All other cases are handled by the `_`. Its important that we give it as the last pattern to match(Any pattern below this will never match)

Answer (score 2):

_ is a placeholder for a variable that doesn't bind to anything. In case statements, it's used as a catch-all. Basically equivalent to an "else" if it were a string of if/else statements.

In this case statement, you're evaluating whether the `changeset` pattern matches to an Ecto.Changeset where valid? is true, and changes includes a password etc...

In all other cases where it doesn't match, the case statement defaults to the `_`, which just returns the changeset in this instance.

You can see a couple more examples here:
http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html

If you haven't read the entirety of the "Getting Started" guide on the elixir-lang.org site, I recommend doing that before progressing further in the Phoenix book. It's worth it to at least be familiar with the vocabulary of the language, even if it's just at a surface level, so that you have some frame of reference for when you run into unfamiliar code in the book.